# AJAX Incorrect Parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Hi I have the following code

**In JQuery:**

```
this.myFunction = function()
{

   var dto =
   {
       id : getID()
   };

   //alert(getID();) to verify that my number is indeed non zero.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Create",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Data Returned: ");
        }
    });
}
```

in C#

```
public void myCFunction(int i)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

When I ran the debugger in Visual Studios, I noticed that the integer in my C# function is always zero despite that the value I pass it is not zero.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(dto),` should maybe be `JSON.stringify(dataPost)`?

Comment: Yeah that was my typo. Let me fix that in the post

Comment: Also, get rid of the `;` in `id : getID();`

Comment: How is the server supposed to know `id` should be translated to the first argument to `myCFunction`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I thought that's what data: JSON.stringify(dto) does

Comment: `JSON.stringify(dto)` translates `dto` to `{"id":12345}`.

Comment: Have you tried changing your method signature (C#) to 'public void myCFunction(int id)', that way your JSON matches data within the function that will be processing it?

Comment: @layoric, yup that's the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in comments, but this is to make it clearer.

Your JSON data needs to match the data that the C# method that is processing the request. 'i' is always 0 because no data is being processing by the method matches 'i'. Eg, it's being passed null data. Changing the data to match the parameter names will fix this problem. Eg,

```
public void myCFunction(int id)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```